# Why I'm not getting the same results from BFGS minimize in Python as the ones in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, minimization

I'm trying to find the mimimum of a function [Minimum of a function with BFGS method](http://www.ou.edu/class/che-design/che5480-13/Optimization%20of%20Chemical%20Processes-Chapter%206.pdf)  (Page 29 of the PDF document)

And I'm not getting the same results as the ones reported in the link, I already try with and without the jacobian with no luck. Any help, will be appreciated.

The code so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def objective(x):
   x1=x[0]
   x2=x[1]
   print ("x1: ",x1,"    ","x2: ",x2)
   return pow(x1,4.0)-2*x2*pow(x1,2.0)+pow(x2,2.0)+pow(x1,2.0)-2.0*x1+5.0

def jacobiano(x):
  x1=x[0]
  x2=x[1]
  jaco=np.zeros(2)
  jaco[0]=4.0*x1-4.0*x2*x1+2.0*x1-2.0
  jaco[1]=-2.0*pow(x1,2.0)+2.0*x2
  print ("dx1: ",jaco[0],"    ","dx2: ",jaco[1])
  return jaco
x0=np.array([1.0,2.0], dtype=np.double)
print(objective(x0))
sol=minimize(objective,x0,method='BFGS',jac=jacobiano, options={'disp': True})
print(sol)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you have incorrectly calculated the Jacobian, in your case `df/dx1` is incorrect.

if `f = x1**4 -2*x2*x1**2 +x2**2+ x1**2 -2.0*x1+5.0`

then `df/dx1 = 4.0*x1**3 -4.0*x2*x1 + 2.0*x1-2.0`

---

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
   x1, x2 = x
   print ("x1: ",x1,"    ","x2: ",x2)

   return x1**4 -2*x2*x1**2 +x2**2+ x1**2 -2.0*x1+5.0


def jacobiano(x):
  x1, x2 = x
  jaco=np.zeros(2)
  jaco[0]=4.0*x1**3 -4.0*x2*x1 + 2.0*x1-2.0
  jaco[1]=-2.0*x1**2.+2.0*x2

  print("dx1: ",jaco[0],"    ","dx2: ",jaco[1])
  return jaco

x0=np.array([1.0,2.0], dtype=np.double)

sol=minimize(objective,
 x0,method='BFGS',jac=jacobiano, options={'disp': True})
print(sol)
```

Output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 4.000000
         Iterations: 7
         Function evaluations: 9
         Gradient evaluations: 9
      fun: 4.000000000002963
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.50324351,  1.0154575 ],
       [ 1.0154575 ,  2.55695728]])
      jac: array([  7.65547714e-06,  -2.90129716e-06])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 9
      nit: 7
     njev: 9
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 1.00000093,  1.0000004 ])
```

**Matlab:**

```
x1=1.00863, x2=1.01932, f=4.00008
```

**Python:**

```
x1=1.00000093, x2=1.0000004, f=4.000000000002963
```

**Optimal solution**

```
x1=1.0, x2=1.0, f=4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was expecting the same results when I was not including the jacobian, why there's such a difference in the decimals?

Comment: The difference in accuracy may be due to the way in which the algorithm was implemented in each language, it could also be due to the types of data that each one uses.

Comment: Thanks! For this example do you have a suggestion for the type of data in Python?

Comment: I do not understand what you expect, observing the results the algorithm implemented in python has more precision than the algorithm done in matlab, the optimal answer is `x1=1`, `x2=1` and `f=4`.

Comment: I do not understand why you want to get the matlab result if it is less accurate.

Comment: I was expecting the result of the iterations very close in decimals, as reported in the link of the example, but as you said it's more accurate, thank you very much again for your time and very detailed answer!